# Count specific words in rdd with python

Tags: python, pyspark

I need to count the different words that start with the letter 'A' in rdd.

I know to count the different words, but I don´t know count words with condition.

```
words= myRDD.distinct().count()
print words
```

Comment: We can help if you don't define what is "rdd".

Comment: Resilient Distributed Datasets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do a filter by starting letter and then count. Something like below:

```
words = myRDD.filter(lambda x: x[0] == "a").distinct().count()
```

Also you can use the builtin function

```
myRDD.filter(lambda x: x.startswith('a'))
```